# How to get the installed video card ( Delphi)

Tags: delphi, video

Looking for a way to find the installed video card (Chip) on a windows computer.

A solution that supports XP thru Win 7.

I am using Delphi 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`Win32_VideoController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class

Try this sample.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;

procedure  GetWin32_VideoControllerInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT Name,PNPDeviceID  FROM Win32_VideoController','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('Name           %s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('PNPDeviceID    %s',[String(FWbemObject.PNPDeviceID)]));// String        
    Writeln;
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_VideoControllerInfo;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode])); 
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;      
end.
```

Comment: We should be able to award badges to community members. I nominate RRUZ for the WMI-Mastery badge. WMI is just SO handy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution taken from @RRUZ answer. I slightly changed it into a function instead to make it easier.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj;

function GetVideoCardName(): String;
const
  WbemUser = '';
  WbemPassword = '';
  WbemComputer = 'localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator: OLEVariant;
  FWMIService: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject: OLEVariant;
  oEnum: IEnumvariant;
  iValue: LongWord;
begin;
  try
    FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
    FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2',
      WbemUser, WbemPassword);
    FWbemObjectSet := FWMIService.ExecQuery
      ('SELECT Name,PNPDeviceID  FROM Win32_VideoController', 'WQL',
      wbemFlagForwardOnly);
    oEnum := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumvariant;
    while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
    begin
      result := String(FWbemObject.Name);
      FWbemObject := Unassigned;
    end;
  except
    on E: EOleException do
      ShowMessage(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message, E.ErrorCode]));
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Classname + ':' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```