# Access the WMI from Delphi

Tags: delphi, wmi

While I understand how I connect to the WMI and get the information's needed , I can't understand what is our need for this **while loop** (`while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do`
) ? From [How to get the installed video card ( Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966946/how-to-get-the-installed-video-card-delphi) :

```
FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT Name,PNPDeviceID  FROM Win32_VideoController','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
begin
  Writeln(Format('Name           %s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]));// String
  Writeln(Format('PNPDeviceID    %s',[String(FWbemObject.PNPDeviceID)]));//   String        
  Writeln;
  FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
end;
```

Comment: There could be more than one video card.

Comment: and what's the technical answer ? I mean why it's = 0 ?

Comment: I didn't interpret that as your question. I understood it as "Why is this loop here?"

Comment: I searched but can't find anything about that 0 . I also read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221369(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The documentation is clear enough. The code should test for S_OK though. The value of S_OK is 0. You need to stay with the problem longer. You had all the information you needed.

Comment: I urge you to be more specific. If you are particularly need comments about that hardcoded `0` - it is a defect, there should be `S_OK` (or `SUCCEED(...)`) there instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`SWbemServices.ExecQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393866(v=vs.85).aspx) method returns a collection with the result of the WMI sentence. This object support  iteration through the [`IEnumVARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221053(v=vs.85).aspx) which is expose via the `_NewEnum` property.

Using a enumerator is the only way to iterate over the results of the returned object (some languages like *vbscript* implement a hidden implicit enumerator and you can access such info using a *for..in* loop over the returned object). In Delphi to have access to such enumerator you must cast the `_NewEnum` property of the returned object  to a `IEnumVariant` interface.

Then you can iterate over the data using the [`Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221369(v=vs.85).aspx) method. The result of this method is documented like so

- **S_OK** The number of elements returned is *celt*.
- **S_FALSE** The number of elements returned is less than *celt*.

***celt*** : is the name of the first parameter and indicate the number of elements to be retrieved for the `Next` method.

On this case we are requesting 1 element at time (check the first parameter of the `IEnumVARIANT.Next` function) so if the return of the function is S_OK (0) means which the function returned successfully 1 element of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Computers may have more than one video card. This loop is simply iterating through each one.

Answer (score 1):

There may be more than one video card, hence the loop.

`oEnum` is an [IENUMVARIANT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221053(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221369(v=vs.85).aspx) returns `HResult` which in this case can be:

> ```
> S_OK    The number of elements returned is celt.
> S_FALSE The number of elements returned is less than celt.
> ```

*Note: S_OK translates to 0 and S_FALSE is 1.*

Comment: For IEnumVARIANT.Next it is said it can return either `S_OK` or `S_FALSE`. [Link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221369(v=vs.85).aspx)